# Recursive Path Finding in 0,1 matrix (and saving all possible paths) java

Tags: java, recursion, matrix

I'm trying to code a recursive method that will find  a path without backtracking to a location within a int matrix , that contains the values 0,1. 0 is okay to step on , 1 is not. I am also restricting a path that is longer then 50 moves.

Location is an object that has row and column values (x,y).
locationEquals is a function that returns  true if two Locations are the same and false if not.
The map variable is the matrix where I am trying to path find in.

```
private static List<List<Location>> options = new ArrayList<List<Location>>();
public static void PathFind(List<Location> path)
{
 Location current = path.get(path.size() - 1);
    boolean done = false;
    if(locationEquals(current,new Location(24,38)))
    {
        options.add(path);
        return;
    }
    if(path.size() > 50) done = true;
    if(!done)
    {
    try
    {
    if(map[current.row][current.col + 1] == 0)
    {
    if(!path.contains(new Location(current.row, current.col + 1)))
        {
            List<Location> temp = path;
            temp.add(new Location(current.row, current.col + 1));
            PathFind(temp);
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
            try
    {
    if(map[current.row - 1][current.col] == 0)
    {
        if(!path.contains(new Location(current.row - 1, current.col)))
        {
            List<Location> temp = path;
            temp.add(new Location(current.row - 1, current.col));
            PathFind(temp);
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    try
    {
    if(map[current.row][current.col - 1] == 0)
    {
        if(!path.contains(new Location(current.row, current.col - 1)))
        {
            List<Location> temp = path;
            temp.add(new Location(current.row, current.col - 1));
            PathFind(temp);
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    try
    {
    if(map[current.row + 1][current.col] == 0)
    {
        if(!path.contains(new Location(current.row + 1, current.col)))
        {
            List<Location> temp = path;
            temp.add(new Location(current.row + 1, current.col));
            PathFind(temp);
        }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    }
```

After executing the following code 'options' is empty, which means that it didn't find a way. but there is definitely a way in this matrix, so it's a bug in my code that I can't find.

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Hint: `List<Location> temp = path;` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: The problem is that I can't debug my program in the environment I'm coding in. It's a webkit of some sort and I have to work with it.  Although when I did use a debugging option of some sort, it showed that somehow the 'path' size got to 50+ and the recursion didn't stop, and it showed that from the first iteration of PathFind, it only went to one option of the 4, when clearly I can branch off to all of the 4.

Comment: [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) help ... please show your attempts to debug this.  Your posted code doesn't have even extra **print*8 statements to track values of intermediate variables.  Follow **path**, for instance.

Comment: @NPE Shallow copy vs Deep Copy ?, if so, How can I change it so I can use temp without changing values that path point at ?

Comment: @EliranZiv To preform a semi-deep copy on your `List` create your new `temp` list and instantiate it as an `ArrayList`.  Then use `temp.addAll(path);` to add all of the items from `path`.  This will allow `temp` to be an independent woman errr `List`

Comment: @CraigR8806 thanks, it works just fine now ! :)

Comment: @EliranZiv Sweet.  Just know that this is not a very efficient way to do this.  There really isn't a clean efficient way to do this.  You will be fine if you keep your `List` size where you're at around 50.  If you're using Netbeans, it has a nifty profiler built in, I'm sure there are others out there, but I would keep an eye on that if you experience any performance problems.

Comment: @EliranZiv But really you shouldn't see any problems unless you let your lists grow to over 25k+ then you might see about 500ms of processing time with that specific line of code

Comment: @CraigR8806 thanks for the in depth information, I'm pretty new to java so I don't know all the cool tricks yet ! . But pretty sure I won't go over 25k, it's just a 45x45 board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not creating a new list every time you go to the next step of the recursion (your temp variable is not really temporary as it is just a reference to your path and not a copy of it).

To solve this, I replaced `List<Location> temp = path;` with `List<Location> temp = new ArrayList<>(path);`

So the code is:

```
private static List<List<Location>> options = new ArrayList<List<Location>>();
public static void PathFind(List<Location> path) {
    Location current = path.get(path.size() - 1);
    boolean done = false;
    if (locationEquals(current, new Location(24, 38))) {
        options.add(path);
        return;
    }
    if (path.size() > 50) done = true;
    if (!done) {
        try {
            if (map[current.row][current.col + 1] == 0) {
                if (!path.contains(new Location(current.row, current.col + 1))) {
                    List<Location> temp = new ArrayList<>(path);
                    temp.add(new Location(current.row, current.col + 1));
                    PathFind(temp);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (map[current.row - 1][current.col] == 0) {
                if (!path.contains(new Location(current.row - 1, current.col))) {
                    List<Location> temp = new ArrayList<>(path);
                    temp.add(new Location(current.row - 1, current.col));
                    PathFind(temp);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (map[current.row][current.col - 1] == 0) {
                if (!path.contains(new Location(current.row, current.col - 1))) {
                    List<Location> temp = new ArrayList<>(path);
                    temp.add(new Location(current.row, current.col - 1));
                    PathFind(temp);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (map[current.row + 1][current.col] == 0) {
                if (!path.contains(new Location(current.row + 1, current.col))) {
                    List<Location> temp = new ArrayList<>(path);
                    temp.add(new Location(current.row + 1, current.col));
                    PathFind(temp);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```